# Operator <<< (shell) in Powershell

Tags: powershell, minikube

I'm creating a .ps1 to automate a few things, one of them is that I need to run `minikube addons configure ingress`, when i run it's like:

```
PS C:\Git\automating\Helm-App\Run-Locally> minikube addons configure ingress
-- Enter custom cert (format is "namespace/secret"):
```

And keeps waiting for me to manually put the value I want, which is `kube-system/mkcert`.

I found a Shell script that has `minikube addons configure ingress <<< "kube-system/mkcert-tls-secret"`. How can I do that in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
"kube-system/mkcert" | minikube addons configure ingress
```